# Is there any way to return a double as a whole number?

Tags: java

```
public static double getTotal() {
    double dice1 = (Math.random()*6) + 1;
    double dice2 = (Math.random()*6) + 1;
    return dice1 + dice2;
}
```

I have this method that is returning the sum of two dice into another part of my code and I was wondering if there was any way to make the sum a whole number before I return it to my main method. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to round it or truncate it?

Comment: @JacobG. yes, I would like to round the sum to the nearest whole number before it gets returned.

Comment: `return Math.round(dice1 + dice2);`

Comment: Make new `Random rnd`, then `return rnd.nextInt(6)+rnd.nextInt(6)+2`